# how to use azure ad without client secret just with client id and tenant id?

Tags: java, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

My question is how to apply user authentication in web application using azure ad in case I don't have client secret. I just have client-id and tenant-id. I would appreciate your swift response.

Comment: Check from the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios) what scenario matches your app.

Answer (score 1):

**AFAIK** there is no need to use client secret in web application while we are authenticating with Azure AD.

While authenticating your App with Azure AD, your **code snippet** will be something like below:

```json
{  
"AzureAd": {  
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",  
"ClientId": "*******************************",  
"TenantId": "*******************************",  
"CallbackPath": "https://localhost/signin-oidc"
}
```

If you want to get access token via **Postman** without using client secret, you can make use of ROPC flow like below:

- In Postman, Go to  **Authorization**  tab and select type as  **`Oauth2.0`**
- Go to **Headers**  tab and include  **`Content-Type`**  key and give value as  ***application/x-www-form-urlencoded***
- In  **Body**  tab, include parameters like client_id, grant_type, **`username`**, **`password`** and scope as below:

[image]

And you will get the **access token** like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks  for your help, but I was  just provided  client id, tenant id ,scopes, issuer and  endpoints I don't have access to password or postman.

Comment: Username and password should be your UPN/mail-id and your password. If you want to try using postman then [install](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) it.

Comment: Is it possible to use just provided client-id and tenant -id to authenticate user in Microsoft graph.

Comment: Yes you can authenticate user in Microsoft graph but need redirect URI of the app.
Check these links: [Ref1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#authorization-request), [Ref2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#request)

Comment: ROPC is not recommended. "Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks that are not present in other flows. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows aren't viable."

Comment: Use Service Principal with Certificate authentication.